# The difference between max and fmax (Cross platform compiling)

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-studio-2010

In Xcode, this compiles fine:

```
float falloff = fmin(1.0, fmax(0.0, distanceSqrd/cRadius));
```

However in Visual Studio 2010 it errors, and I have to use max instead of fmax.
distanceSqrd and cRadius are also both floats.

It's the only part of my code that doesn't seamlessly cross compile...

Any ideas why?

Comment: I am sure your program was a bit longer than that (`#include` ?)

Comment: Well, one originates in C99, the other in C++98 ...

Comment: What is the actual error VS brings? By the way, while *"`distanceSqrd` and `cRadius` are also both floats"*, `1.0` and `0.0` certainly aren't. I hope you `#include`d either `<math.h>` or, much more preferably, `<cmath>` (in which case you should also qualify your calls if you don't have a `using` somewhere. while in VS this shouldn't be neccessary, it is not guaranteed that those functions are available in global namespace when using the proper C++ header `<cmath>`).

Comment: Oh wait, those are actually from `C++11`'s extensions to `<cmath>`, which VS doesn't support yet. Answer found.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The functions `std::fmax` and `std::fmin` from the `<cmath>` header (or `fmax` and `fmin` from `<math.h>`) are a C++11 feature and along with many other new mathematical functions one that *Visual Studio 2010* doesn't support yet (neither does *2012*). So for portability it is advisable to replace them by `std::min` and `std::max` from `<algorithm>`.

The actual difference is, that `fmin` and `fmax` are mathematical functions working on floating point numbers and originating from `C99` (and *might* be implemented intrisically by actual specialized CPU instructions where possible), while `min` and `max` are general algorithms usable on any type supporting `<` (and are probably just a simple `(b<a) ? b : a` instead of a floating point instruction, though an implementation could even do that with a specialization of `min` and `max`, but I doubt this).

They also behave *slightly* different for special floating point arguments. While it is not entirely specified how `min` and `max` will respond to `NaN`s, I think (though from the above definition they should always return the 1st operand), `fmin` and `fmax` are clearly specified to always return the other (non-`NaN`) argument when one is `NaN`, if the implementation is IEEE 754 conformant (which any modern PC implementation usually is).